# Integrating Captcha Into .NET Email Form

Tags: .net, vb.net, email, captcha

I'm having trouble integrating a CAPTCHA into this form I'm using. I have next to no .NET experience so any help will be greatly appreciated! I finally found a contact form that worked (when using an email address from my personal domain - does not seem to work with gmail for some reason).

I managed to get it styled and functional but it needs a CAPTCHA to stop spam from flowing in. I found a pre-made CAPTCHA form on http://www.tipstricks.org/ which works great by itself but I'm really not sure how to get it integrated with the form below. I can get the CAPTCHA to work by itself, and the form to work by itself, but I can't seem to figure out how to get the CAPTCHA to validate AND submit the form.

As it is now when I fill out the form and submit it I get a green confirmation saying the message was sent but a red message saying CAPTCHA failed. The message goes through regardless of what's filled out in the CAPTCHA field.

Quite frankly I'll be happy with any CAPTCHA code, not just what I downloaded. If any of you have a better bit of code or a way to incorporate a CAPTCHA into this form I'll gladly use it instead.

Below is what I'm using for the form. Please let me know if I need to provide more details. As I said any help will be greatly appreciated!

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="test.aspx.vb" Inherits="custom_aspnet_test" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Mail" %>
<script runat="server">   

   Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender as object, e as EventArgs)

        Dim objEMail As New MailMessage()

        objEMail.To = "myemail@email.com"
        objEmail.From = txtFrom.Text

  objEmail.Subject = "Contact Form"
  objEmail.Body = "IP: " & Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR") & vbcrlf & "Date/Time: " &Now & vbcrlf & "Name: " &txtName.Text & vbcrlf & "Email: " &txtFrom.Text & vbcrlf & "Phone: " &txtPhone.Text & vbcrlf & "Comments: " &txtBody.Text
  objEmail.Priority = MailPriority.High
        SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "smtp.address.com"

  try
   SmtpMail.Send(objEMail)
   Response.Write("<font color='green'><strong>Thank you for contacting us. We will respond shortly.</strong></font>") 

  catch exc as Exception
   Response.Write("<font color='red'><strong>Send failure: </strong></font>" + exc.ToString())
  End Try
    End Sub
</script>
<html>
<head>
<title>Contact Form</title>
</head>
<body>

<form id="ContactMain" runat="server">
<table border="0" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
     <tr>
      <td valign="top" class="form-input" colspan="2">
          <label class="form-label-left">Name</label>
      <asp:TextBox runat="server" class="form-textbox" ID="txtName"></asp:TextBox>      
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td valign="top" class="form-input" colspan="2">
          <label class="form-label-left">Email <font color="red">*</font></label>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" class="form-textbox" ID="txtFrom" ></asp:TextBox>    
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat=server 
               ControlToValidate=txtFrom
               ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid Email address">
            </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>                    
        </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td valign="top" class="form-input" colspan="2">
          <label class="form-label-left">Phone</label>        
              <asp:TextBox runat="server" class="form-textbox" ID="txtPhone" ></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td valign="top" class="form-input">
          <label class="form-label-left">Comments <font color="red">*</font></label>
         <asp:TextBox runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" rows="6" cols="40" class="form-textarea" ID="txtBody"></asp:TextBox>
         <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat=server 
            ControlToValidate=txtBody
            ErrorMessage="Please let us know what we can help you with">
         </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>    
       </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td colspan="2" valign="top" class="form-line">
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phTest" runat="server" Visible="true">
            <img src="captcha.ashx" id="imgCaptcha" />&nbsp;<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="RefreshImage('imgCaptcha');">Refresh</a><br />
            Write the characters in the image above<br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCaptcha" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
            <asp:Button Runat = server ID = btnSubmit OnClick = btnSubmit_Click Text = "Submit" class="form-submit-button"></asp:Button>
            </asp:PlaceHolder>
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phResult" runat="server" Visible="false">
            <p><asp:Label ID="lblResult" runat="server" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label></p>
            <asp:Button ID="btnRetry" runat="server" Text="Take another test" />
            </asp:PlaceHolder>
        </td>
     </tr>
     </table>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the code from the file "CodeFile" is referencing:

```
Partial Class custom_aspnet_test
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
        If IsNothing(Session("ASPCAPTCHA")) OrElse Session("ASPCAPTCHA").ToString.Trim.Length = 0 Then
            lblResult.Text = "This test has expired."
            lblResult.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
        Else
            Dim TestValue As String = txtCaptcha.Text.Trim.ToUpper(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"))
            If StrComp(TestValue, Session("ASPCAPTCHA").ToString.Trim, CompareMethod.Text) = 0 Then
                lblResult.Text = "CAPTCHA PASSED"
                lblResult.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Green
            Else
                lblResult.Text = "CAPTCHA FAILED"
                lblResult.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
            End If
            '//IMPORTANT: You must remove session value for security after the CAPTCHA test//
            Session.Remove("ASPCAPTCHA")
            '//////////
        End If

        phTest.Visible = False
        phResult.Visible = True
    End Sub

    Protected Sub btnRetry_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnRetry.Click
        txtCaptcha.Text = ""
        phTest.Visible = True
        phResult.Visible = False
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have two different places where you respond to btnSubmit.  One of them is in the script tag in the .aspx file.  That is where you send the email.  The other place is in the code behind file in the btnSubmit_Click method.  That is where you check the CAPTCHA.

You have the button wired up to trigger two events. Both of them are firing, which is why you always get both results.

You need to move the email code into the btnSubmit_Click to the code behind where the CAPTCHA succeeds.

Here is the updated code behind with the send email method that is called when the CAPTCHA passes.  Also, you need to remove the send email code from the .aspx file and remove this attribute from the btnSubmit button declaration: **OnClick = btnSubmit_Click**

```
Imports System.Web.Mail

Partial Class test
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
        If IsNothing(Session("ASPCAPTCHA")) OrElse Session("ASPCAPTCHA").ToString.Trim.Length = 0 Then
            lblResult.Text = "This test has expired."
            lblResult.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
        Else
            Dim TestValue As String = txtCaptcha.Text.Trim.ToUpper(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"))
            If StrComp(TestValue, Session("ASPCAPTCHA").ToString.Trim, CompareMethod.Text) = 0 Then
                lblResult.Text = "CAPTCHA PASSED"
                lblResult.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Green
                ' The CAPTCHA passes so send the email
                Me.SendEmail()
            Else
                lblResult.Text = "CAPTCHA FAILED"
                lblResult.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
            End If
            '//IMPORTANT: You must remove session value for security after the CAPTCHA test//
            Session.Remove("ASPCAPTCHA")
            '//////////
        End If

        phTest.Visible = False
        phResult.Visible = True
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' This was the code you had in the aspx file.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Private Sub SendEmail()
        Dim objEMail As New MailMessage()

        objEMail.To = "myemail@email.com"
        objEMail.From = txtFrom.Text

        objEMail.Subject = "Contact Form"
        objEMail.Body = "IP: " & Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR") & vbCrLf & "Date/Time: " & Now & vbCrLf & "Name: " & txtName.Text & vbCrLf & "Email: " & txtFrom.Text & vbCrLf & "Phone: " & txtPhone.Text & vbCrLf & "Comments: " & txtBody.Text
        objEMail.Priority = MailPriority.High
        SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "smtp.address.com"

        Try
            SmtpMail.Send(objEMail)
            Response.Write("<font color='green'><strong>Thank you for contacting us. We will respond shortly.</strong></font>")

        Catch exc As Exception
            Response.Write("<font color='red'><strong>Send failure: </strong></font>" + exc.ToString())
        End Try
    End Sub


    Protected Sub btnRetry_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnRetry.Click

        txtCaptcha.Text = ""
        phTest.Visible = True
        phResult.Visible = False
    End Sub


End Class
```